# creating facebook canvas app with cakephp

Tags: facebook, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, facebook-canvas

I'd like to create a Facebook canvas app with CakePhP 2.0. All the tutorials I've found seem to be out of date. Could anyone tell me how I can integrate facebook-php sdk into cakephp 2.0 ?

Any help will be appreciate :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the webtechnik plugin to integrate seemlessly your Cakephp app in to Facebook : https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin